# Not able to get members in a room - XMPP

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I'm getting the names of all groups like so...

```
  func xmppMUC(_ sender: XMPPMUC, didDiscoverRooms rooms: [Any], forServiceNamed serviceName: String) {
    if let elements = rooms as? [DDXMLElement] {
      for element in elements {

        print("Name: \(String(describing: element.attributeStringValue(forName: "name")))")
        print("JID:  \(String(describing: element.attributeStringValue(forName: "jid")))")

      }
    }
    print("rooms: \(rooms)")

}
```

This gives the group names of all the groups. Now how can I get the list of group members who are in each group..?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a room and join it that already exists as below.

```
-(void)joinRoom:(NSString *)groupJid {

XMPPJID *JID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:groupJid];

_xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomHS jid:JID];
[_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_xmppRoom activate:_xmppStream];
[_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:_userNick history:nil];

[_xmppRoom fetchOwnersList];
[_xmppRoom fetchAdminsList];
[_xmppRoom fetchMembersList];
}
```

it would fetch all member, admin and owner list in its delegate method

```
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchOwnersList:(NSArray *)items {
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchAdminsList:(NSArray *)items {
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items {
}
```